# Secure way to import third party web-content to my site so it sends over SSL?

Tags: php, security, ssl

As an example, lets say I'm working with a product that requires I put `<iframe>`s onto my page, which then get embedded into my existing website.

The issue being my website is SSL, and the iframe comes from another origin which is not SSL.

I'm not worried about javascript here as the other origin cannot access the DOM due to same-origin, but my huge concern here is that annoying "mixed content" error in IE that pops up, or the broken lock in other browsers, etc. If a user doesn't know to click "no," they don't get the content-- which is critical to the website.

What I want to do instead is provide a way to take this content and scoop it into my own script so it sends to the browser from my domain with my SSL certificate, for all resources it links to (ie, recursively parse the file and send the resources as my own). I realize this could open a huge hole because it's now coming from my origin.

What recommended approach should I take to get third party content to land on my site? Right now the content I'm pulling is the base HTML file, the CSS, and 9 images, all of which are dynamic. This is simmilar to a proxy I suppose.

Comment: You'd have to build a full proxy in PHP. There's plenty of answers on SO about how to do that.

Comment: You could also use apache mod_proxy to create a reverse proxy to the target web site and expose it somethwere else in your domain or on another port also configured as SSL. The problem as always with such simple proxies will be that if there is absolute links in your target website it will fail. And if it check IP addresses for anything it will fail even faster.

Comment: I don't really want to run a full proxy it basically just needs to grab the HTML and re-write links, I'm mostly concerned about the security aspect.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do instead is provide a way to take this content and scoop it into my own script so it sends to the browser from my domain with my SSL certificate, for all resources it links to (ie, recursively parse the file and send the resources as my own). I realize this could open a huge hole because it's now coming from my origin.

Get a separate domain (`mydomain.com` -> `thirdpartyname.mydomain-proxy.com`) to serve as an HTTPS proxy for third-party content. That way they cannot run JavaScript in the same origin as your website.

Alternatively: Pressure them to adopt HTTPS. [It's fast](https://istlsfastyet.com/) and [it's free](https://letsencrypt.org).